# Catch Exception high in the call stack- when dealing with n tiers?

Tags: java, exception, finally

Say I have 3 tier app- frontend domain and data access. I have read that it is a good idea to catch exceptions high in the call stack...so if I get a data-access exception, the domain layer merely does a finally, like so

try{

}finally{
//cleans up 
}

and lets the data-access exception percolate to the frontend layer. Does this not break layering by making the front-end layer deal with the innards ? I think that each layer should either handler or wrap and throw exception that it cannot handle to its calling layer...
any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of good feedback so far, I'll give you my take.

Rule #1. ONLY catch exceptions you are going to actually handle. By handle, I mean handle in such a way that the client's request can continue. You may catch things long enough to log information (don't abuse this, usually the stack is enough information) or to convert to a different error that propagates easier (ala Runtime based). But, if you can't handle it, don't bother catching it. That's just extra code that is useless and confusing. Even when you log or convert, you end up rethrowing.

Realize that most of the time, you can NOT handle an exception. Truly. Many fail to grasp this. But the reality is, if you get an IOException reading or writing to the disk, game over. That request cannot be completed for the user. If your network is flaky and you can't talk to the database, same thing.

Rule #2. When you do get an exception that you cannot handle, the only thing you can do is try to fail in such a way that it is helpful to the user. This means, log it for later analysis (including original stack/cause), and then report something as helpful as possible to the user. Clean up whatever you must, so that the system remains in a consistent state.

Given that this communication with the end user happens at a very high level, that means you usually have to catch at that level. Most of the time, I find that there is very little value in any exception handling between it's inception point and the top level where you catch it for logging and reporting to the user. I often convert to a form of RuntimeException, but that's only done to ease propagation through the layers.

The biggest and most important thing is to realize that you usually can't handle exceptions, so any code you write for them should be as simple as possible.

Comment: Suppose an exception occurs while trying to deserialize a document from a stream.  If one abandons the partially-constructed document and informs the user that the file could not be loaded, has one "handled" the exception?

Comment: @supercat - Yes. As much as you reasonably could. You may want to provide a good error message, like what went wrong. But, if the document failed to deserialize, what more can you do?

Comment: How should one tell the difference between exceptions which don't corrupt any state other than the abandoned document, from those which indicate a corrupt system state?

Comment: Depends on the exception. These are guidelines, not an excuse to stick your head in the sand. If you catch a SQL Exception, you still need to handle rollback and cleanup. But you need to KNOW that about the SQL Exceptions. There is no discussion here of abdicating your responsibilities as a programmer. Just a discussion of how to propagate exceptions in the system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think layering is such a pure idea that this breaks it.

Wrapping and rethrowing doesn't add much value either.

What's wrong with having the service layer handle exceptions?  That ought to be the end of the line, the last line of defense.  This design lets the service log the exception - once and for all - and send a user friendly message to the UI for display.

Comment: I assume you mean frontend layer when you say services layer ? Wont it clutter the top end of the line layer with code that may require information from layers below it to handle ?  eg: if I have a want to for some reason make the data access call 3 times before giving up, and that state is stored in the layer that just passed it up, how will the frontend layer access it ? wont it make the top layer bulky ? do you have any example code that follows this pattern ?

Comment: No, "service" is not "front end", because that phrase means presentation or view to me.  By definition, if it bubbles up, it means that layers below cannot handle it.  "Handle" doesn't mean log the stack trace - it means doing something about a rare or exceptional situation.  What state do you mean?  If you get a SQL Exception, what else do you need besides the SQL error code and such?  Add it to a custom exception if you must.  I don't think it makes anything bulky.  No sample code.

Comment: lets not name the layers its confusing. I said "frontend domain and db layers" and you replied back with "services" I did not know what in my list you were referring to. So I am going to say Layer1 - layer n(inner most)  In the example I mentioned where handling means retrying 3 times, I need to store the number of times so far somewhere- it should be closest to where exceptioin occured, preferably in the layer n-1 above it. (contd... in next comment)

Comment: Admittedly this is a contrived example but it makes my point about needing state information to handle exceptions, unless ofcourse your routine exception handling is to log it and do nothing else...then I can see how passing it off to the upper layers will seem ok...

Comment: "services" is something new - you don't have it in your app, because neither front end nor db layers fit the bill.  It's something in between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to catch exceptions higher in the call stack, but only to the point that is makes sense.  If the data level can handle and log the exception and just pass a message back to the front-end then that will keep things simple and more flexible.

Personally, if I need to have a try and a finally then I would like to also catch and do something about the situation there rather than pass it up to the caller. Just keep in mind there are always exceptions to good design rules (normally another rule like KISS).

Answer (score 0):

There are three interlocking problems here.

First, constantly re-wrapping exceptions can be done but what value is it providing?  You are just creating more layers around the original exception.  I only wrap an exception when I can provide additional information about the exception or when the first exception causes another.

Second, the idea of an exception is to respond that a function can not be completed normally.  You should catch the exception at the place where it makes the most sense to deal with the problem.  If the code has "another alternative" the exception should be trapped at that point.  Otherwise log it for the user or developer to work out.

Third, the try/finally block.  These are useful when an exception would cause resources to hang out in a open or allocated state.  I always use try/finally to clean up resources that might be left open (my favorite is the Statement/ResultSet from java.sql, a huge memory hog).  A really good programmer has a lot of this in their code as a way to recover gracefully without creating huge memory leaks or resource constraints.